# Making experience unreal

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

How would one say make a situation feel less real? I'm referring to the situation when people create illusory world of theirs to shelter themselves from reality;

Comment: This is a broad question, with potentially many answers. However, if you give usage example on how you plan to incorporate the words/phrases, it might help you get better answers. See the [tag:single-word-requests] tag info for more details.

Comment: "The common usage here is usually fantasy.

Someone can be said to live in a fantasy, or to retreat into a fantasy world, or to create a fantasy around themselves.

The 'fantasy' can be a modified version of reality (e.g. when someone imagines that familiar people are now impostors), or a completely new creation with no similarity to what the rest of us might experience and observe." This is the type of the answer I seek.

Comment: An alternative to "fantasy" (which is the best fit) is "imaginary world".

Answer (score 2):

The common usage here is usually ***fantasy***.

Someone can be said to live in a fantasy, or to retreat into a fantasy world, or to create a fantasy around themselves.

The 'fantasy' can be a modified version of reality (e.g. when someone imagines that familiar people are now impostors), or a completely new creation with no similarity to what the rest of us might experience and observe.

Another possibility is ***delusion***, although that has connotations of an *affliction* rather than a protective (sheltering) retreat.

Comment: This is good but it would be better if you or someone could suggest more alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

- [***Alienate***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alienate): cause to become withdrawn or unresponsive; isolate or dissociate emotionally. *The numbing labor tended to alienate workers.*

You can also alienate yourself. From [aspiescentral.com](https://www.aspiescentral.com/threads/alienating-yourself-from-others-and-that-to-do-about-it.3478/):

> From my own personal experience as well as reading others on this forum, people with AS [Aspergers Syndrome] have a tendency to somehow alienate themselves from others—often leading to exclusion from social activities and feelings of isolation.

- [***Detach***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/detach): cause to become detached or separated; take off.

Again, you can detach yourself from reality. From [wikihow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Detach):

> When a situation becomes too much for you to handle, you might need to detach from it emotionally. Emotional detachment is not recommended as a means of running away from your problems or weathering abuse. It should not be used as a weapon against others or as a substitute for communication. However, if you are going through a tough moment within a relationship, temporary detachment can help you calm down and put your issues into perspective.

- [***Daydream***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/daydream): have a daydream; indulge in a fantasy.
- [***Woolgather***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/woolgather): To engage in fanciful daydreaming.

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: I was going to suggest "Daydream" but decided against it since I wan't sure what OP's exact context was.

Answer (score 0):

To live/be ***[in a world of one's own](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/in-a-world-of-one's-own)*** is an common expression used to convey the idea:

> - Concerned with one’s own thoughts and not aware of what is happening around one:
>
>   - *he is in a world of his own and is frequently carried away by his own flights of fancy*.

(ODO)